# Running app jar file on spark-submit in a google dataproc cluster instance

Tags: java, jar, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running a .jar file that contains all dependencies that I need packaged in it. One of this dependencies is `com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter` and already checked it's class file is in this .jar file.

Unfortunately when I hit the command spark-submit on the master node of my google's dataproc-cluster instance I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter$SleepingStopwatch$1.<init>(RateLimiter.java:417)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter$SleepingStopwatch.createFromSystemTimer(RateLimiter.java:416)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.create(RateLimiter.java:130)
at LabeledAddressDatasetBuilder.publishLabeledAddressesFromBlockstem(LabeledAddressDatasetBuilder.java:60)
at LabeledAddressDatasetBuilder.main(LabeledAddressDatasetBuilder.java:144)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

It seems something happened in the sense of overwriting my dependencies. Already decompiled the `Stopwatch.class` file from this .jar and checked that method is there. That just happened when I ran on that google dataproc instance. 
I did `grep` on the process executing the `spark-submit` and I got the flag `-cp` like this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -cp /usr/lib/spark/conf/:/usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.7.1.jar:/usr/lib/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/usr/lib/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/usr/lib/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/:/etc/hadoop/conf/:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've found, Dataproc includes Hadoop dependencies on the classpath when invoking Spark. This is done primarily so that using Hadoop input formats, file systems, etc is fairly straight-forward. The downside is that you will end up with Hadoop's guava version which is 11.02 (See [HADOOP-10101](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10101)).

How to work around this depends on your build system. If using Maven, the maven-shade plugin can be used to relocate your version of guava under a new package name. An example of this can be seen in the [GCS Hadoop Connector's packaging](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/pom.xml#L249), but the crux of it is the following plugin declaration in your pom.xml build section:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>your.repackaged.deps.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </execution>
      </execution>
    </plugin>
```

Similar relocations can be accomplished with the sbt-assembly plugin for sbt, jarjar for ant, and either jarjar or shadow for gradle.