# How to manage conflicting DataProc Guava, Protobuf, and GRPC dependencies

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, google-hadoop, vitess

I am working on a scala Spark job which needs to use java library (youtube/vitess) which is dependent upon newer versions of GRPC (1.01), Guava (19.0), and Protobuf (3.0.0) than currently provided on the DataProc 1.1 image.

When running the project locally and building with maven, the correct versions of these dependencies are loaded an the job will run without issue. When submitting the job to DataProc, the DataProc version of these libraries are preferred and the job will reference class functions that cannot be resolved.

What is the recommended way of ensuring that the right version of a dependency's dependencies get loaded when submitting a Spark job on DataProc? I'm not in a position to rewrite components of this library to use the older versions of these packages that are being provided by DataProc.

Comment: There's a good chance that you can work around class path issues with relocations and the maven shade plugin. See this answer about relocating a guava version with Spark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922719/running-app-jar-file-on-spark-submit-in-a-google-dataproc-cluster-instance/33925408#33925408

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, since this is gRPC and protobuf, also take a look at how the Bigtable HBase client shades their dependencies: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-hbase-parent/bigtable-hbase-shaded/pom.xml#L77; There's unfortunately quite a bit that goes into properly shading those.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've been able to use maven shade plugin to rebuild the dependent library and shade out conflicts. It works on DataProc which is better than before, but I'm not able to build or develop with IDEA at the moment.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as answer?

Answer (score 3):

Recommended approach is to include all dependencies for your job into uber jar (created using [Maven Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin, for example) and [relocate](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) dependencies classes inside this uber jar to avoid conflicts with classes in libraries provided by Dataproc.

For reference, you can take a look at how this is [done](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/15daebc71c4ca5170e2a5aea712315ec5595044c/gcs/pom.xml#L221:L279) in [Cloud Storage connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/tree/master/gcs) which is a part of Dataproc distribution.