# Json library for Cloud Dataproc

Tags: json, cloud, google-cloud-dataproc, google-data-api

I need to find a json library for Google Cloud Dataproc.
I'm a bit not sure where can find a list of supported json libraries.
Or if I write my own, which dependencies can be taken into Dataproc?

Any data on this topic will be highly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Oleg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about reading/parsing JSON objects, than you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library witch is a [part](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/dependency-analysis.html) of Hadoop distribution on Dataproc.

Also, you can use JSON library of your choice and any other dependencies, but you should [create uber jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) for your job and include all these libraries/dependencies into it.

If you are talking about [Google JSON API Client libraries](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client), than Dataproc by default deploys 1.20.0 version as part of [GCS and BQ](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop) connectors. You still can use newer JSON API Client library version if you will [relocate](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) it inside your job's uber jar to avoid conflicts with version deployed to Dataproc.

See more detailed answer on conflicting dependencies management in Dataproc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50025327/3227693).