# Hadoop security GroupMappingServiceProvider exception for Spark job via Dataproc API

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, jar, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a Spark job on a google dataproc cluster, but get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping not org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:833)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:676)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2430)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2430)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2430)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at com.my.package.spark.SparkModule.provideJavaSparkContext(SparkModule.java:59)
    at com.my.package.spark.SparkModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideJavaSparkContextProvidesAdapter.get(SparkModule$$ModuleAdapter.java:140)
    at com.my.package.spark.SparkModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideJavaSparkContextProvidesAdapter.get(SparkModule$$ModuleAdapter.java:101)
    at dagger.internal.Linker$SingletonBinding.get(Linker.java:364)
    at spark.Main$$InjectAdapter.get(Main$$InjectAdapter.java:65)
    at spark.Main$$InjectAdapter.get(Main$$InjectAdapter.java:23)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.get(ObjectGraph.java:272)
    at spark.Main.main(Main.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping not org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2324)
    ... 31 more
```

**Dataproc versions**: 1.1.51 and 1.2.15

**Job configuration:**

Region: global 
Cluster my-cluster 
Job type:   Spark
Jar files:  gs://bucket/jars/spark-job.jar
Main class or jar:  spark.Main
Arguments:  
Properties: 
spark.driver.extraClassPath:    /path/to/google-api-client-1.20.0.jar
spark.driver.userClassPathFirst:    true

I have no problem running it this way on the command line:

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/path/to/google-api-client-1.20.0.jar" --conf "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true" --class spark.Main /path/to/spark-job.jar
```

But the UI/API does not allow you to pass both the class name and jar, so it looks like this instead:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/path/to/google-api-client-1.20.0.jar --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --class spark.Main --jars /tmp/1f4d5289-37af-4311-9ccc-5eee34acaf62/spark-job.jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar
```

I can't figure out if it is a problem with providing the extraClassPath or if the spark-job.jar and the hadoop-common.jar are somehow conflicting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* this is caused by the combination of userClassPathFirst and /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar being the jar Dataproc specifies to spark-submit. In some cases, the instance of GroupMappingServiceProvider from the user class loader will be used and in others the instance from the system class loader will be used. As a class loaded from one class loader is not equal to the same class loaded from another class loader, you would end up with this exception.

Instead of userClassPathFirst, would it make sense to instead relocate the conflicting classes using something like maven shade?

Comment: Thanks. I am already using maven, so I added relocation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922719/running-app-jar-file-on-spark-submit-in-a-google-dataproc-cluster-instance/33925408).

Now I can get the job started without the extraClassPath, but get a different hadoop error.

`java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec: Provider org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec not a subtype`

Using relocation for the org.apache.hadoop.io.compress did not help.

Comment: Is this with userClassPathFirst or without? Once api-client is relocated in your jar, I would expect you to be able to execute your job without using userClassPathFirst.

Comment: Also without userClassPathFirst `spark-submit --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=false --class spark.Main --jars /path/to/spark-job-SHADED.jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar`

Comment: This runs fine without the hadoop-common.jar: `spark-submit --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=false --class spark.Main /path/to/spark-job-SHADED.jar`

Comment: I forgot to also set the `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=false` also, no more hadoop errors.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that encounters this issue (even if you aren't using **Spark**)

This exception is raised here [Configuration.java#L2585](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-3.0.3-RC0/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java#L2585)

**Configuration.java**
[image: 1]

### Meaning of the Exception

Hadoop is telling you, the second class is **not** a `subclass` or `subinterface` of the other class.

This is what `Class.isAssignableFrom(OtherClass)` does on line `2584` in the image above

> The `java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom()` determines if the class or
> interface represented by this Class object is either the **same as**,
> or is a **superclass** or **superinterface** of, the class or
> interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

But we know that

- `org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider`

Is a **superclass** of

- `org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping`

So how can this happen?

### Why this happens

This can happen for several reasons

1. You have two versions of `hadoop-client` libraries on your `classpath`
2. You've bundled Hadoop with a library, and it's a different version or different release than another bundled Hadoop library.
3. Your classpaths point to multiple Hadoop installations or Hadoop clients when they should only have a single `hadoop-client` jar
4. You are using the wrong Hadoop package - for instance you are targeting **Cloudera** environments and you are using the open source version of Hadoop libs

### Solutions

- Conform all your Hadoop library versions to the same version
- Create a meta package and depend only on this single meta package jar across all your plugins, clients, packages.
- Switch to using the proper release version of your client library - example:

  - Cloudera shaded [`hadoop-client-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client-api/3.0.0-cdh6.3.2)
  - Cloudera shaded [`hadoop-client-runtime`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client-runtime/3.0.0-cdh6.3.2)
- Use shaded versions of Hadoop Client Libs via `hadoop-client-api` and `hadoop-client-runtime`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to turn off `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true` you could check that `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % SPARK_VERSION` dependency is present and scope is defined correctly.
When `spark-core` jar is in classpath exception won't have been thrown.